# Trouble passing AWS API Gateway query parameters to a Python AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have an API which I created using the AWS API Gateway and it has 2 URL String parameters so my GET call is in the following format

```
/endpoint?City=NYC&State=NY
```

I am trying to capture both the City and the State URL String parameters in my Python Lambda function and when I print them out and monitor them in CloudWatch, I see None for both of them. I am not sure what I am missing here

```
import boto3
import json 

def lambda_handler(event, context):
# Extract city and state from query parameters

query_parameters = event.get('queryStringParameters', {})
city = query_parameters.get('City')  
state = query_parameters.get('State')

# Print city and state values
print('City:', city)
print('State:', state)

if not city or not state:
    return {
        'statusCode': 400,
        'body': 'City and State parameters are required.'
    }
```

When I execute the following code, the code is going into the error block and I am seeing this as the output

```
City and State parameters are required.
```

Is there anything else that I may have missed or what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

`event` has a complex format when passed from API Gateway. You have to check and inspect the documented [event format](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-apigateway.html#apigateway-example-event), and get your `city` and `state` according to the that format. Specifically, they will be found under `pathParameters` value in `event`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do an API maybe you can consider use powertools

https://docs.powertools.aws.dev/lambda/python/latest/

Allow to handle the API Gateway calls with a syntax very similar to Flask or FastAPI.
https://docs.powertools.aws.dev/lambda/python/latest/core/event_handler/api_gateway/

Something like this should work with powertools

```py
@app.get("/endpoint")
def get_endpoint(city: str, state: str )
```